# Failed to load ...\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenHtmlToPdf\1.11.0.0_32\wkhtmltox.dll

Tags: .net

I'm using .net Framework v4.5.2 and OpenHtmlToPdf package. When I run the program on the client machine. The program throws this exception: "An error occurred while attempting to create the invoice PDF. RmFpbGVkIHRvIGxvYWQgQzpcVXNlcnNcS8Sxc21ldFxBcHBEYXRhXExvY2FsXFRlbXBcT3Blbkh0bWxUb1BkZlwxLjExLjAuMF8zMlx3a2h0bWx0b3guZGxs"

After a quick search, I found that this text is a Base64 text. And meaning of it : "Failed to load C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenHtmlToPdf\1.11.0.0_32\wkhtmltox.dll"

I tried to shutdown antimalware programs, replace the dll with new one. Nothing happened.
Below is my code:

```
public string GetPdfFilePath(string invoiceId, int invoiceIdx)
        {
            try
            {
                if (invoiceIdx == 101)
                {
                    sessionId = Login();
                }

                string pdfFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + $"{invoiceId}.pdf";

                if (File.Exists(pdfFilePath))
                    return pdfFilePath;

                var html = GetInvoiceHTML(invoiceId);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"{invoiceId} error while getting ETTN");
                }
                var content = OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.From(html).Content();

                //File.Create(pdfFilePath);

                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(pdfFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                {
                    var bytes = content.ToArray();

                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    stream.Close();
                }
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, content.ToArray());


                return pdfFilePath;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("An error occurred while attempting to create the invoice PDF. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }



 string Login()
        {
            try
            {
                var settings = IniHelper.Instance.GetSettings<ErpSettings>();
                string username = $"tx:{settings.EMikroUsername}:br:{settings.EMikroBranch}:ad::ap:";
                string sessionId = client.login(username, settings.EMikroPassword, "v1", false);
                return sessionId;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHelper.Instance.Log(ex);
                throw new Exception("Couldn't sign up! " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason for this problem was that the path contained special characters (username). Once I removed the special character, it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to download appropriate version of the OpenHtmlToPdf from NuGet into your project dependencied. Check out: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHtmlToPdf#supportedframeworks-body-tab